# Use NtQueryInformationProcess to check for debugger attached

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ntdll

I am writing a simple C++ project on Microsoft's Visual Studio 2022, that uses `NtQueryInformationProcess` to check if a process is being debugged but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <winternl.h>
#include<Windows.h>

// Method use Debug flags in the PEB. This worked and return a = 1
int PEB_Flag() {
    int a;
    __asm {
        mov eax, dword ptr fs : [18h]
        mov eax, dword ptr ds : [eax + 30h]
        movzx eax, byte ptr ds : [eax + 2h]
        mov[a], eax
    }
    return a;
}

typedef enum _PROCESSINFOCLASS {
    ProcessBasicInformation = 0,
    ProcessDebugPort = 7,
    ProcessWow64Information = 26,
    ProcessImageFileName = 27,
    ProcessBreakOnTermination = 29
} PROCESSINFOCLASS;


typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* TNtQueryInformationProcess)(
    IN HANDLE           ProcessHandle,
    IN PROCESSINFOCLASS ProcessInformationClass,
    OUT PVOID           ProcessInformation,
    IN ULONG            ProcessInformationLength,
    OUT PULONG          ReturnLength
    );
int main() {
    HANDLE ProcessHandler = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, GetCurrentProcessId());

    HMODULE hNtdll = LoadLibraryA("ntdll.dll");
    //HINSTANCE hNtDll = GetModuleHandleW(L"ntdll.dll");
    std::cout << "hNtdll: " << std::hex << hNtdll << std::endl;

    auto pfnNtQueryInformationProcess = (TNtQueryInformationProcess)GetProcAddress(
        hNtdll, "NtQueryInformationProcess");
    DWORD dwProcessDebugPort, dwReturned;
    NTSTATUS status = pfnNtQueryInformationProcess(
        //GetCurrentProcess(),
        ProcessHandler,
        ProcessDebugPort,
        &dwProcessDebugPort,
        sizeof(DWORD),
        &dwReturned);



    a = int(status);
    std::cout << "Is debugged: " << a << std::endl;

    std::cout << "OK ?";
    std::cin >> a; // I set a breakpoint here
}
```

I build it, run it in both debug mode and realease mode, and it print "Is debugged: 0", which is wrong because this process is being debugged. I know that my code has something wrong, because I had tried with method check for debugger flag and it prints "1".

Comment: `ProcessDebugPort` return not `DWORD` but `PVOID`. `OpenProcess` not need for self process.

Comment: Since you seem to check for the current process, why can't you just use [`IsDebuggerPresent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-isdebuggerpresent)?

Comment: That was too common. I want to research NtQueryInformationProcess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of a call to the `NtQueryInformationProcess` function indicates **only** whether or not the call succeeded (and, if it failed, and indication of the nature of the error). Thus, your `status` variable – assuming the call succeeds – will have the value `STATUS_SUCCESS`, which is defined as zero (whether or not you cast it to an `int`).

The *actual data* that you want to inspect is the `dwProcessDebugPort` `DWORD`, whose address you (seemingly correctly) pass to the system call. That will have a non-zero value if the process is being run under a debugger.

So, after your call to `NtQueryInformationProcess`, your 'diagnostic' code should look something like this:

```
if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
    std::cout << (dwProcessDebugPort == 0 ? "Not debugging.\n" : "Debugging.\n");
}
else {
    std::cout << "Call failed!\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir it work ! In my case dwProcessDebugPort will be 0xFFFFFFFF if process is being debugged, and 0 if not.